# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values' in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I have a dictionary called sortdi with keys as integers and values as strings. I want to store the values into a dataset so I created the following code

```
sortdi = sortFreqDict(dictonary)
dataset = sortdi.values()
```

When I try to run the code, the error that shows up is ,

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

What do I do to store values into the dataset ?

Comment: As the AttributeError says, sortdi is not a dict but a list. What happening is that sortFreqDict is returning a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `sortFreqDict` function returns a `list` not a `dictionary`. To add to a `list` you use `list.append()`.

Try printing `sortdi` and see if that gives you what you were hoping for?